# "can not use FieldCache on multivalued field" during a percentile facet on non-existant field

Tags: solr, faceted-search, solr5

I'm using Solr 5.3.1, issuing percentile facet queries to my index. My index contains mostly dynamic fields (see schema).

An example faceted query -

1. Urlified: [http://host_name:8983/solr/core_name/select?json.facet=%7B%22my_facet_name%22:%22percentile(my_field_num,70.0,80.0,90.0)%22%7D&rows=0](http://host_name:8983/solr/core_name/select?json.facet=%7B%22my_facet_name%22:%22percentile(my_field_name,70.0,80.0,90.0)%22%7D&rows=0)
2. Solr Params:

   - json.facet={"my_facet_name":"percentile(my_field_num,70.0,80.0,90.0)"}
   - rows=0 (because I only need the facet values)

**Sometimes when executing the faceted query I get the following error-**

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: 
Error from server at http://host_name:8983/solr/core_name:
can not use FieldCache on multivalued field: my_field_num
```

**To the best of my knowledge this happens only when the faceted field doesn't exist.** During query time I don't know which fields exists so querying non-existant fields is legit.

The fields I query are always multivalued and most of the times the facet succeeds, so multivalueness mostlikely isn't the issue. See relevant parts of the schema -

```
<schema name="my_schema" version="1.5">
...
    <dynamicField name="*_num" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
...
</schema>
```

Can someone help me shed light on the problem?